# selected row data display in lable or textfield and remove the data if deselect it

Tags: ios

I'm doing the selected tableview row data display in text field and concatinated all selected strings.
I want to remove the unselected data from that concatinated string.
Can any body please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
yourString = [yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:unselectedRowData withString:@""];

yourTextField.text = yourString;
```

Comment: @12345 comma separator is at the end of your concatenated string?? Use yourString = [yourString substringToIndex:yourString.length-1];

Comment: @12345 you can also use '[yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@","]' . it will split your string by comma and will give an NSArray..

Comment: @12345 Above code will give you subString of yourString excluding character at last position in string.. Not working??

Comment: How to store table view 3 rows data temporarily,without using user defaults?

Comment: If i clicked on text field,display the tableview.Already nsarray values show in tableview.In that tableview,selected rows are display with check marks.which rows are checked,those are need to show in textfield with concatination.if I click the textfield again,previous check marked rows keep with check mark only.this is the issue actually.Please give me any guidance to solve this.